# Suma a través un diccionario según el valor

Tags: c#, diccionarios

playerCards es una lista que tiene 3 strings compuestos por una letra en la posición 0 que representa el palo y un numero en la posición 1 (Ejemplos de posibles strings: "B2", "M7", "C4"). Interseccion cuando es igual a 2 muestra que dos de los strings de playerCards son del mismo palo (Tienen la misma letra en la posición 0). EnvidoRanks es un diccionario que incluye todos los posibles strings de playerCards y les da un valor de tipo int. Lo que quiero hacer es que cuando interseccion sea dos sumar las dos cartas del mismo palo a Envido.

```
private static readonly Dictionary<string, int> EnvidoRanks = new()
{
    { "M2", 10 },
    { "M4", 9 },
    { "M5", 8 },
    { "MQ", 7 }, { "O7", 7 }, { "C7", 7 }, { "E7", 7 }, { "B7", 7 },
    { "MJ", 6 }, { "O6", 6 }, { "C6", 6 }, { "E6", 6 }, { "B6", 6 },
    { "O5", 5 }, { "C5", 5 }, { "E5", 5 }, { "B5", 5 },
    { "O4", 4 }, { "C4", 4 }, { "E4", 4 }, { "B4", 4 },
    { "O3", 3 }, { "C3", 3 }, { "E3", 3 }, { "B3", 3 },
    { "O2", 2 }, { "C2", 2 }, { "E2", 2 }, { "B2", 2 },
    { "O1", 1 }, { "C1", 1 }, { "E1", 1 }, { "B1", 1 },
    { "OK", 0 }, { "CK", 0 }, { "EK", 0 }, { "BK", 0 }, { "OQ", 0 }, { "CQ", 0 }, { "EQ", 0 }, { "BQ", 0 }, { "OJ", 0 }, { "CJ", 0 }, { "EJ", 0 }, { "BJ", 0 },
};

void Start()
{
    var interseccion = playerCards.GroupBy(card => card[0]);
    if(interseccion.Count() == 2)
    {
        EnvidoP += ??;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El resultado de un `playerCards.GroupBy(card => card[0])` es una "lista" de "Listas", cada sublistas contiene una colección de los elementos agrupados. Por lo que es algo engorroso trabajar de esa forma, yo te propongo lo siguiente:

```
var interseccion = playerCards.GroupBy(card => card[0]) //Agrupamos para obtener repetidos
    .Where(a=>a.Count()==2) //nos quedamos solo con las sublistas que tengan 2 elementos repetidos
    .SelectMany(a=>a); //aplanamos para obtener una sola lista

if (interseccion.Any()) //si la lista tiene elementos
{
    //usamos un select para obtener los valores desde el diccionario y luego sumar
    int EnvidoP = interseccion.Select(a => EnvidoRanks[a]).Sum();
}
```

Ahora, si no te moleta que `EnvidoP` sea `0` en caso de que la agrupación no retone ningún grupo con 2 palos repetidos, puedes simplemente encadenar todo:

```
var EnvidoP = playerCards.GroupBy(card => card[0])
    .Where(a=>a.Count()==2)
    .SelectMany(a=>a)
    .Select(a => EnvidoRanks[a])
    .Sum();
```

Comment: Perdon pero al poner la primera opcion me salta este error: error CS0136: A local or parameter named 'EnvidoP' cannot be declared in this scope because that name is used in an enclosing local scope to define a local or parameter